# Is a file transfer speed of 1-1.5 MB/s on a Raspberry Pi via Ethernet expected speed? Is there anything I can do to speed up file transfers?

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, file-transfer, sftp

Within a wired gigabit LAN network, I am getting only 1-1.5 MB/s (not Mbps) transfer speeds to/from a Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspberry Pi OS ver 5.4) from a laptop client.

Is this to be expected and any suggestions for faster file transfer?

Speed is the same whether writing/reading from an external hard drive connected to the Raspberry Pi over the USB 2.0 port or onto the microSD card containing the Raspberry Pi’s OS. Tried multiple SFTP clients (WinSCP, Filezilla) enabling more connections to no effect. SCP transfer is the same speed as SFTP. Changing the client’s encryption algorithms didn't alter speeds.

On the Pi, running sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_configand adding the line Compression no that increased speeds to 2-2.5 MB/s but not consistently and I am not sure the above command survives reboot.

I also disabled buffer size optimization in the sftp client software which increased speed up to 3-6 MBps, but also seems to fluctuate wildly often settling back down to around 1 MBps.

The fact that I am not sure why these are working and what these do exactly leaves me very unsure if this is a correct/full/sensible answer.

Comment: You completely forgot to mention the bandwidth of your Ethernet connection, download speed can be limited by many things,  physical bandwidth is the bottleneck, though generally ISP's will not let you to reach full physical bandwidth...

Comment: edited to say gigabit